# Linq is very slow with predicate and order by clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

We have List holding 20K objects which contains dates into it. We want to find most recent date from that list considering one condition. Using code as below.

```
listObject.Where(r => r.Date <= asOfDate).OrderByDescending(r => r.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is taking too long than expected. 
Can you please help what would be the better way to do it?
Thank You!

Comment: did you try something like: `var max = listObject.Where(r => r.Date <= asOfDate).Max();`?

Comment: We have few other properties also in the list, max will give us only Date object

Comment: what about regular `for` loop?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is feeding the list? Database? Since you mentioned Linq-to-Entities

Comment: This list is getting generated from a calulator, complete C# list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do (based on @Barns comment)

```
var maxDate = listObject.Where(r => r.Date <= asOfDate).Max(r => r.date);
var item = listObject.FirstOrDefault(r => r.date == maxDate);
```

this will only loop over your list twice instead of sorting it.

Comment: If i remember correctly in case of linq to objects it will loop up to 3 times, depending on how many objects are filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___0___0__):

```
listObject
    .Where(r => r.Date <= asOfDate)
    .Aggregate((acc, curr) => curr.Date > acc.Date ? curr : acc)
```

Performance-wise it can be improved moving filtering logic inside the `Aggregate`  and introducing null accumulator with null handling inside, but if performance is a big concern just switch to `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have three operations:

`.Where(r => r.Date <= asOfDate)` - time complexity O(n)

`.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date)`- time complexity (I imagine) O(n log(n))

`.FirstOrDefault();`- time complexity O(0)

You could do the following an get the same result:

`var maxDate= listObject.Where(r => r.Date <= asOfDate).Max(r => r.date);` - time complexity O(n)

`var result = listObject.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Date == maxDate);` - time complexity O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine Where and Max operations like this:

```
var maxDate = listObject.Max(r => r.Date <= asOfDate ? r.Date : DateTime.MinValue);

var item = listObject.FirstOrDefault(r => r.date == maxDate);
```

This will run over the list only twice.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried sorting the collection first?

```
listObject
.OrderByDescending(ordr => ordr.Date)
.Where(obj => obj.Date <= asOfDate)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This just mean ordering a longer list - I would expect it to be slower.